# Bad input to double variable

Tags: c

I have iput two double variable in c and I need if one of the input is string terminate with print message i try something like this

```
double a, b;
printf("Input two variables:\n");
scanf("%lf %lf", &a, &b);
printf("%lf\n", a);
printf("%lf\n", b);
if(( a <= 0.0 ) || (b <= 0.0))
{
  printf("Bad input\n");
  return 2;
}
```

if I try input 4 fff (or fff 5) the program not print Bad input message.
Why this program not print Bad input message if set a=444 b=fff or a=ddd b=78?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Conjugation, typos, punctuation...
I know a neat form does not make a good question, but it's not really pleasant to read...

Comment: check the return value of `scanf()`. Period.

Comment: Thi is my first try in C

Comment: try this `printf("%E\n", a);`
`printf("%E\n", b);`  and you see the variables aren't equal 0.0 when inputs are 'ffff' etc.

Comment: @mardon: Where did you get the idea that bad inputs will set your variables to non-positive values?

Comment: because input must be positive double number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You try and use `a` before validating whether the input is valid. This could lead to unexpected behavior. You need to validate your input, something like:

```
if (scanf("%lf %lf", &a, &b) != 2) {
    // handle bad input
}
```